# how to validate YAML front matter in a markdown file using program

Tags: yaml, markdown, jekyll

I have a set of markdown files that use YAML syntax for front matter . on passing these files to my jekyll project to build site , i have a set of html files generated . But if any of these files have improper front matter , they remain as .md files and not converted to html .

Now i need to validate the files for front matter before moving them into jekyll project . how can i achieve this ? is there any API or method to validate the file programmatically ?

Comment: i had seen the other question , but they had provided a link (http://www.yamllint.com/)  to test a file . but i need to check it using methods or API in a program

Comment: i am not processing a full .yaml file , i need to validate a front matter content in yaml format for a markdown file . i will give this markdown file as a input for the my jekyll project .